# Finding out the middle point in mergesort in Python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I have written two different implementations of mergesort algo with only one difference, that of formula used in finding the middle point of the array to divide it.

First implementation : (Runs correctly)

```
def mergesort(arr):
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = int(len(arr)/2)
        left = mergesort(arr[:mid])
        right = mergesort(arr[mid:])
        return merge(left,right)
    else:
        return arr

def merge(left,right):
    final = []
    while len(left) > 0 or len(right) > 0:
        if len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
            if left[0] < right[0]:
                final.append(left[0])
                del left[0]
            elif right[0] < left[0]:
                final.append(right[0])
                del right[0]
        elif len(right) > 0:
            final.extend(right)
            right = []
        elif len(left) > 0:
            final.extend(left)
            left = []
    return final


arr = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
print ("List before sorting:",arr)
final = mergesort(arr)
print ("After sorting:",final)
```

Second implementation (Gets into an infinite loop):

```
def mergesort(arr):
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = int(start + (end - start)/2)
        left = mergesort(arr[:mid])
        right = mergesort(arr[mid:])
        return merge(left,right)
    else:
        return arr

def merge(left,right):
    final = []
    while len(left) > 0 or len(right) > 0:
        if len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
            if left[0] < right[0]:
                final.append(left[0])
                del left[0]
            elif right[0] < left[0]:
                final.append(right[0])
                del right[0]
        elif len(right) > 0:
            final.extend(right)
            right = []
        elif len(left) > 0:
            final.extend(left)
            left = []
    return final


arr = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
print ("List before sorting:",arr)
final = mergesort(arr)
print ("After sorting:",final)
```

I have seen the second formula used in case of quicksort algo. The question is if my objective is to divide the array (as in the case of quicksort) why does it goes into an infinite loop.

I am very puzzled and can not come to any logical conclusion.

Can someone please throw some light into the matter? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Ask yourself what the second loop does when `arr` has `len(arr) == 2`

Comment: Not sure if i follow correctly Patrick. If len(arr) == 2 which loop would create a problem . Can you please elaborate a bit more . Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `len(arr) == 2`, then (in `mergesort`) `start` is `0` and `end` is `len(arr) -1 = 1`.  Then `mid` is `int(0 + (0 + 1)/2) == 0`.  Since you're splitting at index `0`, one of the sublists is of length `0` and the other is of length `2`.  You have an infinite loop of length `2` loops

Comment: Yes now i understand ! Thanks a million !... But this same formula is used in case of Quicksort too . That also is a divide and conquer algorithm. Why does it work in that case ? I mean there also we split an array in two right ?

Comment: I suspect if you set `end = len(arr)` it would work fine

Comment: Yes it did ! How do you suggest i make an informed choice in such cases. Should it be trial and error always ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method should be used when working with a single array rather than multiple instances of a sub-array. Instead of using actual separate sub-arrays, the original array is split into logical sub-arrays via an index range. The mergesort function would take 3 parameters, mergesort(arr, start, end), and the caller would call mergesort(arr, 0, len(arr)). The merge function would take 4 parameters, merge(arr, start, mid, end).

Efficiency could be improved using an entry function that takes one parameter, mergesort(arr). It would allocate a single working array tmp and pass that to the internal functions, the call from mergesort(arr) would be mergesort(arr, tmp, 0, len(arr)). The mergesort function would be mergesort(arr, tmp, start, end). The merge function would be merge(arr, tmp, start, mid, end).

Answer (score 0):

(start index of array + (end index of array - start index of array)/2)